# Deserialize nested JSON with RestSharp Client

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'd like to consume a REST Api and deserialize the nested JSON Response. I created the classes using json2csharp.com.

**JSON to consume**

```
{
  id: 32,
  name: "test supply object",
  formId: 4,
  sortOrder: 0,
  created: 1572902163907,
  creator: "jsingler",
  attributes: [
    {
      id: 144,
      attribute: {
        attributeName: "Description",
        attributeType: "TextArea",
        id: 8
      },
      attributeValue: "for development testing. do not delete or use."
    },
    {
      id: 145,
      attribute: {
        attributeName: "Quantity",
        attributeType: "NumberLong",
        id: 10
      },
      attributeValue: "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

**JSON2CSHARP.COM output**

```
public partial class Asset
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "formId")]
    public int formId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sortOrder")]
    public int sortOrder { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "created")]
    public long created { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "creator")]
    public string creator { get; set; }
    public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
}

public partial class Attribute
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ida")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "attribute")]
    public List<Attribute1> attribute { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "attributeValue")]
    public string attributeValue { get; set; }
}

public partial class Attribute1
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "attributeName")]
    public string attributeName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "attributeType")]
    public string attributeType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ida1")]
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

**Method to consume API data**

```
public static List<Asset> GetAllAssets()
{
    var client = new RestClient("URL_USED");
    var request = new RestRequest();
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("USERNAME", "PW");
    var response = new RestResponse();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        response = await GetResponseContentAsync(client, request) as RestResponse;
    }).Wait();

    var AssetList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Asset>>(response.Content);

    return AssetList;
}
```

That always errors with:
`` An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PVF_Web.Models.Attribute1]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '[0].attributes[0].attribute.attributeName', line 1, position 158. ``

And then when I am able to get the JSON to deserialize, it doesn't return the attributes (the true purpose of the application).

Any suggests or thoughts would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

```
[HttpPut]
public void Send(Asset newJA, int Qty)
{
    var client = new RestClient("URL_TO_USE" + newJA.id + ".json");
    var request = new RestRequest("", Method.PUT);
    request.AddObject(newJA);

    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("USERNAME", "PW");
    client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
          Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
          Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);
     });
}
```

This always fails.

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON being parsed.   The sample looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. Go to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and check all the errors.

The property names must be between quotes and if you want it to be an array, you need to make it an array adding the square brackets - [ ] - to the beginning and end of you json.

Comment: The JSON is formatted correctly. I just pasted the sample JSON that Chrome had rendered into a more readable format.

Answer (score 0):

First be sure your json is valid . You can have a look this [side](https://jsonlint.com/) 
**The json properties must be inside quotes** "" like this

> "id"

.

Beside this your root object is not a list . So you have to change your deserializing code to:

```
var AssetList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Asset>(response.Content);
```

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. I'm having issues formatting my RestSharp Put statement now.

Comment: @AaronComstock glad to hear this. Than I will be glad if you can upvote and sign as right answer if it solved your problem.